# Compiling dart to separate js files

Tags: dart, dart2js, angular-dart

I am trying angular.dart. When I compile dart to js it generates a single file which is containing my dart code and whole of angular and may be other libraries also. The problem is file size becomes too large ( 1.5L+ lines ). This also means whenever I will make even a small change in my file, whole js file will be changed and hence can't be cached. Is there a way by which I can have different js files: 1 for my code, 1 for angular and for other libraries.

How do you guys slove this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

The amount of lines has nothing to say about the file size. Is the file really to big?

You could use [`DefferedLibrary`](https://api.dartlang.org/docs/channels/stable/latest/dart_async/DeferredLibrary.html) to split up your application into multiple files, but that won't help you as the file are coupled very close to each others and change both after recompiling (due to tree shaking). But this can help your load time as parts of the application can be loaded later on demand.

But if your application is really to big and have slow load times, you may take a look into the [`MirrorsUsed`](https://api.dartlang.org/docs/channels/stable/latest/dart_mirrors/MirrorsUsed.html) annotation to exclude mirrors information for parts of your application.

Comment: The size of JS file in my case is 5.26 MB. My code is hardly of  10 lines. So I feel the remaining size is of dart libraries used in my code and they should also have compiled. What I feel is that there should be way by which dart libraries can be compiled to different js, so that they can be cache separately and I can change my code whenever required without need of loading all libraries again.
Having everything compiled to a single, I am not been able to take benefit of caching.

Comment: MirrorsUsed is critical for Angular apps at the moment. You should see a JS size on the wire of less than 200kb.